# Django Landing page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I know that in Django for example if I have the home app, I can create it's landing page so that when a user goes to `domain/my_app`, it directs them to the index of that `app`.

Now I want to do the same for the whole website, a global landing page, so it will stop giving me a 404 when I reach to `domain/`

Answer (score 3):

This is handled in **`urls.py`**.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Links to this page will be written as`<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Well you can include a URL pattern that **matches all possible URLs** with:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^my-fancy-homepage/$', views.home, name='home'),
    # other urls
    # ...

    url(r'^.*/$', views.takeoff_page, name='takeoff_page'),
]
```

So the `takeoff_page` will match *all* possible URLs (that are *not* matched by the previous URLs).

As a `view`, you then redirect them to a your real page:

```
# views.py

def takeoff_page(request):
    return redirect('home')
```

So the view of the `takeoff_page` will redirect us to the "landing page" (here called home).